# Dealing with special characters in String

Tags: string, vba, excel, character, special-characters

I am downloading some files which have some chineses characters sometimes and apparently `String` doesn't recognize them.

Any ideas on how I could tell VBA the following :

*If there are some unknown characters in the filename then delete them and only keep the first part of the filename which contains normal characters.*

Actually each of those special characters will be replaced by a "?".

But the problem is that `Msgbox InStr(1, AttachmentName, "?")` will return 0 even though `MsgBox AttachmentName` will display some "?".

I did the following, but as I said above, the "?" are displayed on `MsgBox` but not truly there so it never satisfies the condition...

```
If InStr(1, AttachmentName, "?") <> 0 Then
     AttachmentName = Mid(AttachmentName, 1, InStr(1, AttachmentName, "?") - 1) & "unknown characters "
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sub removes all Chinese characters from a string.

```
Private Sub RemoveChinese()

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim Ch As String
    Dim n As Integer

    Txt = Selection.Text

    For n = 1 To Len(Txt)
        Ch = Mid(Txt, n, 1)
        If Asc(Ch) = AscW(Ch) Then Fun = Fun & Ch
    Next n

    MsgBox Fun
End Sub
```

The point is that Chinese characters are represented by 2 bytes whereas it takes only one to write a Latin character. You must have Chinese language support installed on your computer in order to be able to actually depict them. Hence the `?` inserted for unrecognised characters.

Comment: I would recommend making your variable names a bit more descriptive, particularly in case anyone has this problem in the future. Even with knowing what you are doing it is difficult to follow the logic of your example since readers don't know `Fun` from `Ch` from `Txt` (as far as their purpose goes).